# If $w$ is the $n$_th root of unity and $|z-w^k|\le 1$ then prove $z=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $w$ is the $n$_th primitive root of unity and $|z-w^k|\le 1$ then prove $z=0$.(for all $0 \le k \le n-1$)

**My attempt**:We know that $w^k$ generates all roots of unity if $n$ is even by drawing the roots we can find two points that have the distance $2$ and are on diameter of a circle with radii $1$ and center $0$ so because $z$ has the distance at max $1$ from each point $z=0$.

**Edit**: $n>1$

Comment: @quasi No need to add primitive if $w$ is not primitive then again $w^k$ generates all $n$_th roots of unity.

Comment: It's not true if $w = 1$.

Comment: With $w\neq1$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses Is $w=1$ a primitive root?As I know not. .except for $n=1$.

Comment: Actually, you don't need primitive, you only need $w \ne 1$.

Comment: @quasi Yes but the original problem includes primitive.

Comment: If $n\ge3$ pick three and note that you know their circumcircle.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Could you explain more?

Comment: Given $n\ge3$, what is the circumcircle of the triangle formed by the three points $w^r,w^s,w^t$, for any three integers $0\le r<s<t\le n-1$?

Comment: Consider $\sum_{k=1}^n|z-w^k|^2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understood that part but why the only appropriate point is the center of circumcircle?It needs to prove that the point that has the minimum distance from the farest vertex is the center of circumcircle.Which I don't think is always true.Anyway I like too see an answer instead of comment if it is possible.Thanks.

Comment: Moving closer to one of the three points moves it farther from another one (if the center is inside the triangle.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why is that true?

Comment: Think about three circles of radius 1, one centered on each of the three vertices of the triangle. Are there any points in all three of them, other than the origin?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you explain more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For a point $M$ on the unit circle, the region $|z-z_M|\le 1$ correspond to the interior of the disk $\overline B(z_M,1)$.

Since the point $A=(1,0)$ is always a $n$-th root of unity, let's fix the blue disk.

Now, let's take two points $B$ and $C$ on the unit circle, associated to the green and pink disks.

When $C$ is located inside the dashed area **[figure 1]** of points that are located in the lower semi-plane delimited by $(OA)$ and the higher semi-plane delimited by $(OB)$ then the intersection of the $3$ disks is reduced to $O$.

While when $C$ is outside this region **[figure 2]**, then the intersection in orange is not empty (i.e. not reduced to 1 point).

The case $n=2$ of square root of unity, correspond to only two disks with $B=(-1,0)$, in that case these two disks are tangent in $O$ and $z=0$ is the only solution.

For $n\ge 3$, let's associate $B$ to the primitive root of unity $w=\exp(\frac{2i\pi}n)$ and $C$ to the root $w^k$.

We shall see that there always exists $k\in[2,n-1]$ such that $C$ belongs to the dashed region.

This condition translates to :

$\arg(z_C)\in[\pi,\pi+\arg(z_B)]\iff \pi\le\frac{2k\pi}n\le\pi+\frac{2\pi}n\iff n\le 2k\le2n+2$

$\forall n\ge 3,\ k=\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor+1$ satisfies this condition.

So $O$ is the only intersection of the three disks, meaning $z=0$ is the only solution of the $\forall k,|z-w^k|\le 1$ problem.

---

*Edit: 16/09*

When angle $\hat B$ is small, simple geometric considerations on semi-planes show why the dashed area is important.

When $2$ centres are aligned then the corresponding $2$ disks are tangent. If you move $C$ above $(OA)$ an intersection between the two disks is created in upper semi-plane delimited by $(OA)$. If you move $C$ below $(OA)$ then an intersection is created in lower semi-plane delimited by $(OA)$. This is the same for the disks issued from $B$ and $C$ now realtively to semi-planes delimited by $(OB)$.

It is then straightforward to see that when $C$ is in the dashed area, the intersections belong to disjoint angular sectors $[\hat B,\pi]$ and $[\hat B+\pi,2\pi]$ at least for $\hat B$ small enough.

Yet for the case $n=3$, $\hat B$ is as large as $\frac {2\pi}3$ and the intersections span over wider areas, it is still possible to have a geometric argument, but in this case I'll prove it by algebra.

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$ be in the $3$ disk intersections when $C$ is in the dashed area :

$\begin{cases}
|z-a|\le 1 & a=1\\
|z-b|\le 1 & b=e^{i\beta} & 0<\beta<\pi\\
|z-c|\le 1 & c=e^{i\gamma} & \pi\le\gamma\le\pi+\beta \iff \gamma=\pi+\lambda\beta,\ \lambda\in[0,1]\\
\end{cases}$

$|z-c|^2=(z-c)(\bar z-\bar c)=\underbrace{z\bar z}_{r^2}+\underbrace{c\bar c}_1-\underbrace{(z\bar c+\bar zc)}_{2r\cos(\theta-\gamma)}\le 1$

This leads to the system

$\begin{cases}
\cos(\theta)\ge \frac r2\\
\cos(\theta-\beta)\ge \frac r2\\
\cos(\theta-\gamma)\ge \frac r2\\
\end{cases}$

$f(\lambda)=\cos(\theta-\gamma)=\cos(\theta-\pi-\lambda\beta)=-\cos(\theta-\lambda\beta)$.

$\begin{cases}
f(0)=-\cos(\theta)\le-\frac r2\le 0\\
f(1)=-\cos(\theta-\beta)\le-\frac r2\le 0\\
\exists \lambda\in]0,1[\ \mid f(\lambda)\ge\frac r2\ge 0
\end{cases}$

This condition on $\lambda$ can be realized only if $\theta$ and $\theta-\beta$ are at least $\pi$ apart, but this implies $\beta\ge\pi$ which is a contradiction.

So the only solution is $r=0$. (which is also $z=0$).

Comment: Could you upload the image another where?My computer can't open pictures in SE sites.

Comment: That site is blocked in Iran try another if possible.

Comment: Can you email it?

Comment: done, you can delete, you personal info from public view now.

Comment: "When C is located inside the dashed area [figure 1] of points that are located in the lower semi-plane delimited by (OA) and the higher semi-plane delimited by (OB) then the intersection of the 3 disks is reduced to O."Why do we have so?

Comment: @TahaAkbari Post updated.

Answer (score 2):

Put $z-\omega^k=u_k$. We have $z\omega^{-k}=1+u_k\omega^{-k}$. Adding and taking in account that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega^{-k}=0$ we get that $-n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k\omega^{-k}$. As $|u_k\omega^{-k}|\leq 1$, we get that $|u_k\omega^{-k}|= 1$ for all $k$, ie $|z-\omega^k|=1$ for all $k$. This imply that $|z|^2-\overline{z}\omega^k-z\omega^{-k}=0$ for all $k$. Adding for $k=0,\cdots n-1$ gives $n|z|^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $|p| = 1$. Any nonzero point $x$ in the half-plane $\{x: \; x \cdot p \le 0\}$ has $|x-p| > 1$.  So if you have points $p_j$ on the circle such that there is no $x$ with $x \cdot p_j > 0$ for all $p_j$, there is no nonzero $x$ with all $|x - p_j| \le 1$.  In particular, this is true whenever $0$ is in the convex hull of the $p_j$.  In your case with $p_j = w^j$, $0 = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{w^j}{n}$.

Comment: can you elaborate please , what do you mean by $x.p\leq 0$ ? is it the scalar product ?

Comment: Yes, the dot product.